# 'Runtime died. Automatically restarting.' when running Keras model with a large amount of data

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory

I'm running a simple Keras model (taken from the keras MNIST example) with my own custom training images and labels. Each image is of size 150 by 150.

I have 81472 images in the training set and 20368 images in the test set.

As soon as I run the Keras model, Colabs shows 'Runtime died. Automatically restarting.'

Comment: How large is the data? Does the training work if you sample the data? It's possible you're simply running out of memory.

Comment: Thanks @BobSmith. Yes, the training does work if I use a smaller set of data, with maybe 20000 images in total. I believe that I may need to use `model.train_on_batch(x, y)` or `model.test_on_batch(x, y)` or `model.fit_generator(data_generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're running out of memory and the system is hence restarting.